# Ckfinder file upload fails with error 404

Tags: ckeditor

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        CKEDITOR.replace('Source',
        {
            filebrowserBrowseUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Content/ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html")',
            filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Content/ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images")',
            filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Content/ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash")',
            filebrowserUploadUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Content/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?command=QuickUpload&type=Files")',
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Content/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?command=QuickUpload&type=Images")',
            filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Content/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash")'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Fileupload doesn't work. I get 404 exception. How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, make sure that `~/Content/ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html` and `~/Content/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx` returns the correct files.

Comment: thanks now ıt works @Nenotlep